# MySQL Combining (Inner Join and Select) efficiency

Tags: mysql

I have two tables A and B.
I need two columns from table A (var1 and var2) and only one column from table B (var3).
Is it more efficient to do

```
SELECT var1, var2, var3 FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON (a.var1 = b.var1)
```

OR

```
SELECT var1, var2 FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN (SELECT var1, var3 FROM TABLE_B b) b_min ON (a.var1 = b_min.var1)
```

The second one reduces # of columns in Table B before being joined but seems more "complex"

Comment: Are there indexes on both `TABLE_A.var1` and `TABLE_B.var1`?

Comment: I'd say the 1st one is much better.  In my experience, `JOIN`s are better than subqueries.

Comment: @Rocket, Yes, I've added indexes on Edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the first one.  In the 2nd one, any indexes on `TABLE_B` will be lost when you do your subquery.

The number of columns has no effect on the query's efficiency.  It's the number of *rows* that does.  The number of rows that MySQL needs to scan is what slows down queries, not the number of columns.

P.S. Make sure there are indexes on `TABLE_A.var1` and `TABLE_B.var1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the 2nd paragraph!

Answer (score 0):

I rather use the first one. Actually there is no need to use a subquery because you do have any aggregation function or manipulation inside it.